# Can you display a line series with x and y value pairs using LiveCharts?

Tags: wpf, livecharts

I am trying to display a line chart by providing x and y value pairs that get displayed by a cartesian chart. Is this possoble with LiveCharts? I can't find an example for this online.

I know, that you can provide the labels for the x axis, but my values on the x axis are not linear, therefore they should have different spacing.

This is my Xaml so far:

```
<liveCharts:CartesianChart Grid.Column="0"
                           Margin="5 0 5 0"
                           Series="{Binding TemperatureSeries}">
    <liveCharts:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <liveCharts:Axis Title="Zeit"
                         FontSize="15"
                         FontWeight="Bold"
                         Labels="{Binding Labels}" />
    </liveCharts:CartesianChart.AxisX>

    <liveCharts:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        <liveCharts:Axis Title="Temperature (°C)"
                         FontSize="15"
                         FontWeight="Bold"
                         LabelFormatter="{Binding DoubleToStingConverter}" />
    </liveCharts:CartesianChart.AxisY>
</liveCharts:CartesianChart>
```

This is how the TemperatureSeries Property looks like.

```
this.TemperatureSeries =
    new SeriesCollection
    {
        new LineSeries
        {
            Values = new ChartValues<double>(),
            Stroke = redStroke,
            Fill = redFill
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `Mapper` e.g. `CartesianMapper<T>`. The `Mapper` maps the data of an arbitrary object to the chart's axis (e.g. *x* and *y* in case of the `CartesianMapper`).
The `Mapper` also allows to define constraints regarding the presentation of the data values. For example you can define that values exceeding a certain threshold should be painted red.
Then assign this data mapper to the `LineSeries.Configuration` property.

Note that `ChartValues` is a generic type that allows to define any data model as chart value. The `Mapper` knows how to get the values out of this model type. The following example uses a simple `Point` struct as data model:

```
private void InitializeData()
{
  var values = new ChartValues<Point>();

  // Create sine graph
  for (double x = 0; x < 361; x++)
  {
    var point = new Point() {X = x, Y = Math.Sin(x * Math.PI / 180)};
    values.Add(point);
  }

  this.TemperatureSeries = new SeriesCollection
  {
    new LineSeries
    {
      Configuration = new CartesianMapper<Point>()
        .X(point => point.X) // Define a function that returns a value that should map to the x-axis
        .Y(point => point.Y) // Define a function that returns a value that should map to the y-axis
        .Stroke(point => point.Y > 0.3 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.LightGreen) // Define a function that returns a Brush based on the current data item
        .Fill(point => point.Y > 0.3 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.LightGreen),
      Title = "Series",
      Values = values,
      PointGeometry = null
    }
  };
}
```